# Video Tag Buttons not showing properly

Tags: html, html5-video

So, this is my first time fiddling with Videos in my websites, and for some reason the video controls (in iOS at least, haven't tried Android) are showing weird:

[image: Video controls showing weird]

As you can see, the buttons are blank and outside of the video. I'm using Bootstrap for the responsiveness.

This is my code:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3 mx-auto" style="max-width: 800px">
        <video controls="true" autoplay  >
          <source src="/Resources/videos/proposito_spectrum_ww.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Any help will do! .. Thanks!

Comment: I think it is good. Please remove style="max-width:800px" and check video player.

Comment: I appreciate it, @Jinny ... apparently the issue was a combination of the max-width, with the bootstrap embed-responsive class. I handled the responsiveness myself and issue was solved!